BeautifulSoup works when running code from the python command line, but not when running a python script from a shell script
I am interested in extracting data added to a database each day using a cronjob.  The cronjob is supposed to run at hourly increments to extract the data by executing a shell script that then runs a python script.  The error message I receive when running the shell script to execute the python script results in the following:
for i in '${madis_sources}'
++ python /Users/estrobach/Python_Scripts/Urban_Evaluations/madisData.py  
acarsProfiles
*2024-07-18 2024-07-19 -80 -74 37 43 False
2024-07-18 00:00:00
/Users/estrobach/Data/acarsProfiles/
point
acarsProfiles
False*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/estrobach/Python_Scripts/Urban_Evaluations/madisData.py", line 25, in <module>
    dat=madisImport(Date,database,Type,source,archive)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 21, in madisImport
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 643, in **http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found**

The line where the error occurs in madisData.py is related to this command:  dat=madisImport(Date,database,Type,source,archive).  The exact error in the madisImport.py file is located in line 21 as referenced above which pertains to this line of code: urllib.request.urlretrieve(f, DataDump + fname)
The execution of this line leads to the error response shown above.  Interestingly, if I run the python code using the python command line, the error does not occur and I get the data I need.  It only occurs when I run the python script using a bash script.  Note that the python version is the correct version for both instances.
I expected to get the data I needed from the current day since I'm using the same code to extract archived data (i.e., data before today).  I thought that since the present day wasn't over yet, that the code was looking for hours within the present day that had not happened yet.  Turns out that wasn't the issue.  I also checked for python version consistency.  Other than that, I can't really think of what would cause an issue when running the code from a shell script.  It works just fine when putting the lines into the python command prompt.

Just in case the data location online is needed:  https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov/madisPublic1/data/point/acarsProfiles/netcdf/

When you run under cron you don't get the same environment as when you login and use a shell. Check for environment variables you have exported and your PATH as set up in your bash/login profile.

Thanks.  I haven't even run cron yet.  The next step would be to set up a cron, but I haven't done that since the issue relates to running a python script with a shell script.  What's interesting is that I don't receive this issue when accessing an archive data link, for example:  https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov/madisPublic1/data/archive/2021/09/15/point/acarsProfiles/netcdf/. Note that I run the same set-up when getting archived versus current data.

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

Having said that, for i in '${madis_sources}' clearly looks like a quoting error. Possible duplicate of Difference between single and double quotes in Bash and When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

The loop is not the problem.  As mentioned previously, this worked fine for archived data online but becomes problematic when trying to bring down today's data.  The code is unchanged between archived versus realtime data.  Would you like me to edit the question to include the entire code?

Here's some more python code for context...
url='https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov/madisPublic1/data/point/acarsProfiles/netcdf/' #defines the location online where today's data can be retrieved
f=url+yr+mn+dy+'_'+hr+'00.gz' #defines name of file within url
Example output for 'f':  'https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov/madisPublic1/data/point/acarsProfiles/netcdf/20240718_0000.gz'
fname = Source+'_' + f.split('/')[-1] # this is the name file where data will be stored on local machine once unpacked
urllib.request.urlretrieve(f, DataDump + fname) # where error occurs.

Note that the line where the error occurs does not happen when executing commands from python's command line.  The issue is when running a shell script to execute the python script.  Again, the shell script works when retrieving archived data, so in principle, this should also work with today's data.
